# How can I align them nicely?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

Those are the labels that receive the data.

There is a lot of space, but there is overlap.

Comment: You have to give height to "Title" Label

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried several times, but I couldn't solve it. So I cleared the constraints and set it up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should arrange your component from the top of the page:

all of your components arrangement and constraints depend on together.

Component_1 must have Constraint(height, top, left, right)
Component_2 must have Constraint(height, top, left, right)
if you have a label with the flexible height you should set constraint without fixed height and should height Constraint with >= height (height >= 30, top, left, right) and set numberOfLine to 0.

if you have a lot of components you should use ScollView or TableView

Comment: Thanks, my friend. I followed your directions but I can't solved. So deleted all the constraints and set them up again.

Comment: This solution is common, you are right.